# Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer kestrel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I am having the below error in my .net core application

> Error -4077 ECONNRESET connection reset by peer

What does this exactly means ?

I have noticed if kept my application in idle state for long time like 1 or 2 hour then this error occurs,

Also,I have already handled the session timeout in my application which works well for given stipulated session time out, Lets say 30 minutes, but if it goes beyond this for long time then I get the above error.

And, i am not using any sockets in my application.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Did you look at this GitHub issue? https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/388

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yes, but doesn't find any solution in it !